# Question deleted by Community

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574085/showing-an-ideal-is-not-equal-to-bbb-zi) is interesting, but I found it deleted by Community.

I'd like to know who actually delete the questions under this generic name, and what are the the reasons behind such decisions.

Comment: Automatic deletion by the Community bot. No answer (the one answer it had was deleted by owner), no activity, negative score, that makes an auto-deletion after 30 days. You can find details on meta.so if you're interested.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!

Comment: De nada. If you find it interesting, vote to undelete. I'm still reading the question to ponder.

Comment: @DanielFischer I just did it!

Comment: @Daniel When I vote to undelete I get the message "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted". This seems wrong. User votes should trump those of a bot.

Comment: @BillDubuque Then [Community](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) deletions count as moderator deletions in that respect, I didn't remember. Flag it for moderator attention and explain why you think it should be undeleted. Moderators can. But somebody should do something with that post when it is undeleted, otherwise it will be deleted again in a month or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four types of automatic deletion of questions: after 9 days (certain closed questions), after 30 days (downvoted unanswered questions, also migration stubs), and after 365 days (0-score unanswered questions). The details are [found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006).

In an earlier implementation of this process, automatic deletions were done with no record in the question's history,  [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9836001/revisions). Such undocumented deletions were reversible by   users. But now they are attributed to Community ♦, which has a diamond: hence, no undeletion by users other than mods. This was pointed out in  [Should questions removed automatically for inactivity really be non-undeletable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167500) and more
recently came up in [Do not auto-delete questions that have been undeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207933).

It is not   clear if this behavior was    intended; in any case, it should not be difficult to change.  But from the look of things, it appears that few people take interest in autodeleted questions, and none of those who do work for SE.